# problem setting up django cant run " manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django

my situation : i have windows 10 ppython 3 on the pycharm terminal i type *pip install django* success
Then I create a folder named "pycal". On the command prompt I went to the folder "pycal". Then django-admin.py startproject newproject. This is successful.
Then I run python manage.py runserver. It tells me
"The system cannot execute the specified program"
any feedback would be really appreciated

Comment: can you show me sacreen shot of your project structure?

Comment: And you changed to the folder `newproject` before starting `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: Also try with `python3 manage.py runserver`, to be explicit. It shouldn't matter, but sometimes it does.

Comment: @tanveerahmad sure mate

Comment: @tanveerahmad i cant share images but i can give you a look of what i did on the terminal  (venv) C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pyshop\pycal\pycal> python3 manage.py runsever
The system cannot execute the specified program.

Comment: check it bruh and response me as well.. u have done or not and please accept my answer as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\pyshop\pycal\ here just simple type


cd newproject
```

after that  just write

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Brother u have to first see folder name which contain manag.py file 
u must have in that directory first 
when you type django-admin startproject PROJECTNAME then u have to in PROJECTNAME folder where your manage.py file resides then u can run the server